# How do I route internet destined traffic through VPN on a Server 2008 box acting as a gateway?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have 2 NICs on this server. The server in this discussion is the gateway and is responsible for routing all internet traffic on the network. All local networking runs through adapter "LAN" and all internet traffic runs through adapter "WAN".

I already have a PPP VPN configured on the server and can make a connection. The traffic generated on the server (in a browser for instance) is routed through the VPN. The LAN traffic destined for the internet however, does not know how to leave the server anymore. When the VPN is active, all the LAN devices loose internet.

How might I go about routing all LAN traffic that is destined for the internet on the WAN adapter, through my VPN connection properly? I would like that every bit of data leaving this network is run across the VPN. If the VPN is not active and cannot transport data securely to the internet, then no data should leave the WAN adapter.

Here is a simple schematic of the desired effect:
[Simple network diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmPsL.png)

Comment: I presume you mean PPTP, not PPP, correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. PPTP is fundamentally insecure. If you value security, you should use another VPN technology.
2. Your VPN clients' default gateway will need to point to an IP address on the other end of the VPN tunnel.
3. Once #2 is set up, you'll need to ensure that your server is configured to NAT traffic from the VPN subnet.